# Get position of hash in array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a bunch of hashes within an array. Each hash contains info about a specific student. I find the student with the highest score (`'student_score'` key) like this:

```
  top_student= array.max_by{ |k| k["student_score"]}
```

Then I want to write a message like this:

```
  puts "The smartest student is (xxxxxx) with a test score of  #{top_student}"
```

Where `xxxx` should be the number of the student (his position in the array).

I need to know which student it is (this info is not a key/value pair within the hash). I thought of doing something with determining the order of the hash within that array but I'm not sure.

How can I get the position of the student?

Comment: "this info is not a key/value pair within the hash" - looks like it should be.

Comment: How does the input `array` actually look like? Please post an example.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see your attempt to solve this. Saying "it's too long" just means you have to reduce it until it demonstrates only the problem you're talking about. Remember, a description isn't nearly as useful as actual code. "mcve" above goes into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of hashes, each hash representing a student:

```
students = [
  {'score' => 10, 'name' => 'Bob'},
  {'score' => 20, 'name' => 'Tom'},
  {'score' => 60, 'name' => 'Pete'},
  {'score' => 50, 'name' => 'Ane'}
]

best_student = students.max_by{|student| student['score']}
```

After you get the student with the highest score, you can find his position in the array with the [`#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-index) method:

```
index = students.index(best_student)
#=>2
```

So you can do this:

```
puts "The best student is #{best_student['name']}, number #{index+1}, with a score of #{best_student['score']}."
#=>The best student is Pete, number 3, with a score of 60.
```

On a side note, the position of a student in an array in your app shouldn't represent info about the student, that info should be saved as an additional attribute in the hash. Imagine if you sorted the array for some reason, that valuable data would be lost. I think you would be much better off if you made an array like this:

```
students = [
  {'id' => 1, 'score' => 10, 'name' => 'Bob'},
...
]
```